Openshift Alertmanager config for Slack channel
we are starting to use openshift alertmanager so that it sends us a report based on our config to slack channel. Right now we are using this config to send us a report
receivers:
  - name: Default
    slack_configs:
      - channel: ocp-test-alerts-default
        send_resolved: true
        api_url: >-
          <our-slack-webhook>
        title: >-
          {{- if eq .Status "firing" }}:rotating_light:{{- else if eq .Status "resolved" }}:white_check_mark:{{- end }} [{{ .Status | toUpper }}]: {{ .Alerts | len }} {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }}
        text: |-
          {{ range .Alerts }}
          • :memo:*Summary:* {{ .Annotations.summary }}
          • :mag:*Description:* {{ .Annotations.description }}
          • :books:*Namespace | Pod:* {{ .Labels.namespace }} / {{ if .Labels.poddisruptionbudget }}{{ .Labels.poddisruptionbudget }}{{ else }}<>{{ end }}
          • :link:*Runbook:* {{ if .Annotations.runbook_url }}<{{ .Annotations.runbook_url }}|URL>{{ else }}No URL{{ end }}
          • :clock1:*Start Time:* {{ .StartsAt.Format "02.01.2006 15:04:05" }}
          


          
          




          {{ end }}
          • :globe_with_meridians:*External URL:* <{{ .ExternalURL }}|URL>
          • :label:*CommonLabels:*
          {{ range $key, $value := .CommonLabels }}
            - {{$key}}: {{$value}}
          {{ end }}
  - name: 'null'
  - name: Watchdog
route:
  group_by:
    - namespace
  group_interval: 1m
  group_wait: 30s
  receiver: Default
  repeat_interval: 2m
  routes:
    - matchers:
        - alertname = Watchdog
      receiver: Watchdog
    - matchers:
        - alertname = InfoInhibitor
      receiver: 'null'
    - receiver: Critical
      matchers:
        - severity = critical

And the message is something like that
 [FIRING]: 2 UnmanagedRoutes
• Summary: Route owned by an Ingress no longer managed
• Description: This alert fires when there is a Route owned by an unmanaged Ingress.
• :books:Namespace | Pod: corporate-banking-test / <>
• :link:Runbook: No URL
• ⏰Start Time: 08.12.2024 17:43:42
enter code here

enter code here
• Summary: Route owned by an Ingress no longer managed
• Description: This alert fires when there is a Route owned by an unmanaged Ingress.
• :books:Namespace | Pod: corporate-banking-test / <>
• :link:Runbook: No URL
• ⏰Start Time: 08.12.2024 17:43:42
enter code here

enter code here
• External URL: URL
• ️CommonLabels:
 - alertname: UnmanagedRoutes
 - container: route-controller-manager
 - endpoint: https
 - instance: 10.100.0.94:8443
 - job: route-controller-manager
 - namespace: corporate-banking-test
 - openshift_io_alert_source: platform
 - pod: route-controller-manager-64786f6984-j86hj
 - prometheus: openshift-monitoring/k8s
 - service: route-controller-manager
 - severity: warning:globe_with_meridians:External URL: URL

And my question is - is there any better to handle these reports? Like for example sometimes its error that not containing pod, basically what I am asking where can I find a best-practice tips to handle this alerts to slack config
